# Changing a div width using css transition

Tags: css

there.I want to enlarge my div toward 2 directions left and right.But my div goes only to the right.How can i fix that? Here is my code.Thanks for help in advance.

```
div {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: red;  
transition: width 2s;
transition-timing-function:linear;
}
div:hover { width: 300px; }



<div></div>
```

Comment: because you are using margin-left... it will fix your div margin from left..

Comment: use alignment-adjust:central;  and delete --> margin left

Comment: It goes to the left without margin-left as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  transition: width 2s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}
div:hover {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```